# ActionBarSherlock API?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to convert my UI to ActionBarSherlock, but I haven't been able to find any sort of public API for it....is there one?

I'm especially interested in the methods that provide access to fragments and the actionbars for compatibility with older versions of Android (pre 3.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [usage documentation](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) for ActionBarSherlock is available online. It has an "Action Bar API" section with statements like:

> The API exposed by the ActionBar instance is an exact duplicate of that which the native method exposes. Refer to its documentation as well as the articles on how to utilize its functionality in the "Related Links" section.

> I'm especially interested in the methods that provide access to fragments

ActionBarSherlock does not "provide access to fragments". It uses the Android Support package as the backport of fragments.

Comment: so basically ActionBarSherlock just provides the look it provides, and the backwards compatibility (via the support package)?

Comment: @Ethan: ActionBarSherlock provides a backport of the action bar. That's why it is named ActionBarSherlock and not UsedRutabagaSherlock.  :-) The Android Support package provides backports of a variety of things, most notably the fragment framework. Note that ActionBarSherlock, at least in its current iteration, simply passes requests through to the native action bar on Android 4.x devices; it uses its own action bar implementation on older devices.